# Grunt globbing pattern not working as expected within grunt-contrib-watch

Tags: gruntjs, glob, grunt-contrib-watch

In *grunt-contrib-watch* I want to watch for changes in both `<%%= yeoman.app %>/*.html` and changes to any HTML file one folder deeper.

Therefore, my watch task looks like this:

```
watch: {
    html: {
        files: ['<%%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html'],
        tasks: ['copy:html', 'replace', 'processhtml:dev']
    }
},
```

When I save changes to `<%%= yeoman.app %>/index.html`, the watch task runs as expected. However, when I create a directory inside `<%%= yeoman.app %>` then create `newfile.html` inside that new directory, *watch* doesn't get fired.

I have also tried `files: ['<%%= yeoman.app %>/*.html', '<%%= yeoman.app %>/*/*.html']`, and even `files: ['<%%= yeoman.app %>/**/*.html']` to match all sub directories, but still *watch* doesn't fire when an HTML file inside the sub directory is edited.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I think your underscore template is malformed. Try this instead:

```
files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/**/*.html']
```

Running `grunt watch --verbose` will give you a list of all files that will be watched by the task. Make sure the paths you expect to be watched are in there.

Comment: Changing from `<%%=` to `<%=` causes the browser to hang, and besides all the rest of my tasks use `<%%=` format with no issue. Running `watch --verbose` simply states `Verifying property watch.html.files exists in config…OK`

Comment: If you don't get any files listed when using the `--verbose` option then grunt isn't watching any files. You should get a bunch of lines like: `Watching some/path/to/example-file.html for changes.` Can you switch out the dynamic `<%%= yeoman.app %>` with an explicit directory that you know is valid, use the `/**/` syntax, and see what the `--verbose` option spits out?

Comment: When I switch to a non-dynamic path: `app/**/*.html` I get the same problem - it responds to changes to `app/index.html` but not to changes to a newly created `app/new_dir/index.html`. Running `--verbose` does list all the HTML files I expect, but after creating `new_dir/index.html` I have to stop _watch_ then restart it to get it to watch `new_dir/index.html`.

Comment: Ah. Looks like this is a known issue; have a look on the issues tracker for further information. https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/166